# How to pass a TempData to my _Layout.cshtml view

Tags: c#, .net

In my _Layout.cshtml I have a navbar that I would like to upload with a picture of the user logged into the system. In other parts of the code I can normally pass the data I want, however, I don't know how to pass a TempData with the photo link to the Layout.

This is the TempData that I use on my controllers and I would like to send it to _Layout.cshtml

```
var information = _employee.ReturnsDataFunctional (userUser);
TempData["photo"] = information[0]["photo"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your data into a ViewBag variable on the ActionMethord.

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var information = _employee.ReturnsDataFunctional (userUser);
    var photo = information[0]["photo"];
    ViewBag.photo = photo;
    ....
    ....
    ....
    return View();
}
```

Then call it on your _Layout.cshtml

```
<div class="round avatar" id="profilepic">
    <img src="@ViewBag.photo"/>
</div>
```

Comment: What controller will I place this IActionResult on?